# sending audio blob from angular to flask server to save it

Tags: angular, flask, audio

hello im working on a project in which i need to send an audio recorded from the user microphone and  store it in flask server i am using RecordRTC for that the audio generated is in blob format im am using angular as front end this is the code
app.component.html

````
                  <button (click)="stopRecording()" class="btn btn-danger" *ngIf="recording" style="cursor: pointer;background-color: red;color: white;font-size: 20px;"> Stop Recording </button>
                  
                  <audio controls="" *ngIf="url"  >
                  <source [src]="sanitize(url)" type="audio/wav"  >
                  </audio>
                  <br>```
````

app.component.ts

```
* processRecording Do what ever you want with blob
  * @param  {any} blob Blog
  */
  processRecording(blob) {
  this.url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
 
  console.log("blob",this.b);
  console.log("url", typeof(this.url));
  console.log(" url is :", this.url);
 
  
  this.sc.audio_browser(blob).subscribe(data=>this.text=data);
```

services.servives.ts```

```
audio_browser(blb: any)
  {var filename = new Date().toISOString();
    var fd=new FormData();
    fd.append("audio_data",blb, filename);
 
    return this.http.post<any>("http://127.0.0.1:5000/audiobrowser", fd, )
    
    
  ;}
```

app.py

````
@app.route('/audiobrowser', methods=['GET,''POST']) 
def audiobr():
    if request.method == "POST":
         f = open('./file.wav', 'wb')
        f.write(request.files["audio_data"])
        f.close()
    
        return(jsonify("success"))```
````

Iam getting an error POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/audiobrowser 405 (METHOD NOT ALLOWED)
how can i solve this error ?

Comment: Can't see the source of the `/audiobrowser`. Do you have writing access on the *file.wav*? Possible answers: [Handling HTTP 405 on the blueprint level · Issue #1494 · pallets/flask](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/1494)

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Posts containing 'flask 405' - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=flask+405)

Comment: @eapo yes i have writing acess